# Secure android app with firebase authentication?

Tags: android, firebase

I am in the process of developing an android application which I intended to publish to the PlayStore soon. I was doing some research and apparently a lot of android apps can get hacked due to the nature of PlayStore with downloading APKs and decompiling to view source codes. I will be using firebase authentication which will include a google-services.json . Is there a way to secure this file or is this file harmless? Google/Firebase says its fine to just add to app folder, but i'm not sure? AND is there anyway of securing firebase auth - i am not using any database firebase facilities as i am using my backend , so I do not need to write any security keys for firebase database??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is google-services.json safe from hackers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508516/is-google-services-json-safe-from-hackers)

Comment: You'll have to be specific about what "securing" means for you, as each hack is different and we can't give a blanket statement here. What specific abuse are you concerned about?