# Jenkins Android Gradle Bild Fail

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play-services

I'm start learning Jenkins for Android. I have setup Jenkins with Docker on my macosx. and start Jenkins using this command to create virtual path to my local AndroidSDK

> docker run -p 8080:8080 -v
>   /Users/foo/bar/Android/sdk:/var/android_home -p 50000:50000 -v
>   jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts

However, I cannot build project becuase google-service.json is missing from my git repository.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDevDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Mappening Project/app/src/dev/debug/google-services.json
  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Mappening Project/app/src/debug/dev/google-services.json
  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Mappening Project/app/src/dev/google-services.json
  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Mappening Project/app/src/debug/google-services.json
  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Mappening Project/app/src/devDebug/google-services.json
  /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Mappening Project/app/google-services.json
```

The question is since google-service.json should not include in repository, what should be the solution ??

## EDIT

I know the error, but don't want to include this file to remote repository and Jenkins connect to my remote repository to build, but without this file.

**So, it's because of this file [should not be on remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37359108/2077479) what should be the solution ???**

Comment: `google-services.json` this file is missing in and should be app folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866061/error-file-google-services-json-is-missing-from-module-root-folder-the-google)

Comment: no no, I know the error, but don't want to include it to remote repository and jenkins connect to my remote source to build but without this file, it's because of this file should not be on remote repository what should be the solution ???

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is keep you .json file in macosx system and while building process you can copy that file in your project folder once git pull is completed.

Comment: Did this worked for you?? If you need help for copying file let me know I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugins in order to solved my requirement.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin