# Flutter: Do I need to share the firebase_options.dart file

Tags: flutter, firebase, github

I am using firebase for my flutter project using cli which gives me this file firebase_options.dart as this file contains lot of information about the project like appid, apikey, projectId and more.

As I want to publish my project on Git Hub will there be any issue if i share the file, if not please answer.
How to hide a file in GitHub

Comment: There are really a lot of separate questions here, but to your first point: the data in `firebase_options.dart` is configuration data that is required for your app to find the Firebase project on Google's servers and is **not** a secret. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public/37484053#37484053 --- Whether you should commit the file to git is a separate consideration. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358340/should-i-add-the-google-services-json-from-firebase-to-my-repository